# how to remove color from mac terminal

Tags: bash, command-line

When I am on the Mac, the terminal is bringing up colors on the path, is there a way to remove them? This is what I have:

[image: terminal path color]

Comment: Google for *"PS1 prompt bash"*; hint look in `/etc/bashrc`

Comment: This is a property of your shell (ie `bash`, `tcsh`, or `zsh`), not osx

Comment: Please show us the contents of your `PS1` (i.e. `echo $PS1`) and what shell you're using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this by adding this to the bash_profile file:

Open the bash_profile:

```
vi .bash_profile
```

Append this at the end of the file:

```
export PS1="\e[0;34m[\u@\h \w]\$ \e[m "
```

Save and close the file.

Final result: The path is in blue `0;34`, `\u` gives you the username `\h` gives you reduced host name and `\w` gives you full working directory.

Complete options available:

```
\u = your username
\H = full hostname, e.g. bob.example.com
\h = reduced hostname, e.g. bob
\w = full working directory, e.g. /home/jamie/bin
\W = basename of the working directory, e.g. bin
\t = time in 24-hour format
\# = command number
\$ = root identifier; $ for regular users, # for root
\T = time in 12-hour format
\l = terminal device, e.g. tty4
\j = number of background/suspended processes
```

Answer (score 1):

Go into your Terminal's `Preferences` pane and navigate to;

`Settings` > `Advanced`

Click `Display Terminal as:` (or something similar, haven't got language on English there) and choose a non-color display-method;

[image: Terminal list]

Comment: Wouldn't that remove all colour from the terminal output? I am not 100% sure that the OP wants to remove all colour or just the colour from the prompt.